# selenium grid: start / stop programmatically

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have two questions ?

Question 1. I use two machines (hub + node) for my tests. I want to start the selenium server by using my code , so basically put a START server and STOP server in my before/after suite sections . Need to know the best way to do that and to check if the server is running or not as well

Question 2. How can i start the server on my remote machine by using code?

My environment is eclipse+java+testNG

Thank You!!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but it sounds like using Jenkins with the Selenium Plugin can give you the features that you want.  Is there any particular reason you want to start and stop the server in your before/after sections?

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:

I think you can build a batch file like this:

```
call java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role hub
```

Now, you can execute (@before suite) that .bat file with java:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c c:/[batchFile].bat");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    p.getInputStream()));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
```

Checking string "line" you'll know if your server works or not.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, this is an easy solution for the HUB. Need something similar also for the remote NODE machine :-)

Comment: Hi, you can try PsExec.exe from PsTools.
 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx


Like this:  PsExec.exe \\[Remote_server] c:\script.bat

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to run .bat file not in project directory. How can I redirect path to my expected directory, tks!

Comment: If I understood well your question... You only need to change the .bat path. For example d:/yourotherfolder/[batchFile].bat.